# Missing logs using NLog and Kibana

Tags: c#, kibana, nlog

I have a situation where I'm trying to log XML using NLog. We view the logs in Kibana.

Logging generally works fine but today I am trying to log an api response which is 320,000 characters long and it is "disappearing". By disappearing I mean that I search for the log prefix in kibana and it doesn't show my log.

As a test I have inserted test logging before and after my actual log:

```
_logger.Info("api Response - About to log");//test
_logger.Info($"api Response: {Environment.NewLine}{xml}");
_logger.Info("api Response - Logging Complete");//test
```

`xml` is a string of XML 320,000 characters long.

Searching Kibana for "api Response" returns both test logs but not the xml log. If I search based on the timestamp of the test logs there is another log I suspect is my missing log:

> message:ï¿½ï¿½koï¿½HÇ¿ï¿½Å}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½x|É»ï¿½ï¿½c#*Zï¿½ï¿½jï¿½ï¿½Ó¢m ï¿½ï¿½*ï¿½}Ç4ï¿½ksï¿½bï¿½Ú*ï¿½ï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½3]ï¿½ï¿½=ï¿½ï¿½lï¿½X-7ï¿½bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½3yï¿½ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½"*'ï¿½

Looks like it may be gzipping the response as it's so large.
Does anyone know if nlog or even kibana would zip the log? I can't see any settings that would make this happen.

If I replace the xml in the log with a random string, it is logged successfully. So it must be something to do with either the format of the xml (perhaps it needs escaping??), or the size of the log.

**Note that if I debug locally, the xml is logged to a text file on my laptop.**

Can anyone shed any light on what is/may be happening? I'm pretty new to NLog and Kibana.

Comment: What is the data type of `xml`?

Comment: `xml` is a string

Comment: What encoding does it use?  What encoding does your log file use?

Comment: The local log file that does contain the xml log is ANSI

Comment: Your xml is probably UTF-8 encoded.  Change your log encoding to UTF-8 and see if that resolves it.